# Não consigo pegar o valor de um asp:hiddenField no c#, está sempre vazio

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou com um problema estranho aqui. Estou atribuindo valor a um `asp:hiddenField` via javascript (já testei dando `alert` e ele  mostra o valor correto), mas depois quando tento pegar o valor dele no C# o `meuHiddenField.Value` é vazio, retorna "". O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e resolvi buscando o valor dele que era enviado junto ao `form` na requisição.

```
var valor = Request.Form["meuHiddenField"];
```

ou

```
var valor = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$meuHiddenField"]; // Se o campo estiver dentro de um <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

Comment: tentei fazer com o request Request.Form["MainContent_meuHiddenField"]; e também retornou "";

Comment: Experimenta `Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$meuHiddenField"]`

Comment: Já tentei isso também e nada; ta muito estranho!

Comment: Qual o valor que o `Request.Form.AllKeys` está vindo?

Comment: ctl00$ConteudoPrincipal$tcNavegacao$tpPesquisa$hdnStatus

Comment: Seu campo é o `hdnStatus`? Se for você precisa fazer `Request.Form["ctl00$ConteudoPrincipal$tcNavegacao$tpPesquisa$hdnStatus"]`

Comment: Funcionouuuuuuuu Descobri. estava analisando o código aqui notei que estáva chamando o click do botão antes de atribuir o valor ao hiddenField hehe.

Comment: Tranquilo, obrigado pelo retorno!

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de se acessar o valor do `HiddenField`, ou de qualquer outro componente de servidor, é usando a propriedade `UniqueID`:

```
string valorHiddenField = Request.Form[hdfCampo.UniqueID];
```

É mais seguro do que utilizar `"ctl00$MainContent$meuHiddenField"`, pois esse formato de nome é gerado pelo `ASP.NET` baseado no nome do `ContentPlaceHolder` da `MasterPage`.

Answer (score 1):

será que no *isPostBack* sua página não esta adicionando um novo valor no hiddenfield e por isso esta vazio ? vc tem algo que monta, preenche algo nesse campo ? se tiver coloque ele dentro do

```
if(!isPostBack){
 muda/cria valor hiddenfield
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante que você postasse um pedaço do seu código para podermos te ajudar melhor.

Como não posso comentar por ainda não ter reputação suficiente, segue abaixo uma amostra de código para um problema parecido com o seu e veja se consegue tirar proveito.

Asp.net

```
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="aspHiddenField" />
   <input type="hidden" id="inputHidden" value='<%= aspHiddenField.ClientID %>' />
```

JavaScript

```
   var inputHidden = document.getElementById('inputHidden');
   $("#" + inputHidden.value).val("texto");
```

C#

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspHiddenField.Value))
   {
      //Seu código
   }
```

Comment: <div runat="server" style="visibility: hidden">
        <asp:Button ID="btnUm" runat="server" OnClick="btnUm_Click" />
        <asp:HiddenField id="hdnUm" runat="server" />
    </div>

Comment: function teste(tst){    
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ConteudoPrincipal_wucTreeviewDinamicaTELA_btnUm').click();
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ConteudoPrincipal_wucTreeviewDinamicaTELA_hdnUm').value = tst;
        alert(document.getElementById('ctl00_ConteudoPrincipal_wucTreeviewDinamicaTELA_hdnUm').value);
        }

Comment: protected void btnUm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          String varTeste = Request.Form["ctl00$ConteudoPrincipal$wucTreeviewDinamicaTELA$hdnUm"];
    }

Comment: acima estão as 3 partes HTML javascript e C#

Comment: Funcionouuuuuuuu Descobri. estava  analisando o código aqui notei que estáva chamando o click do botão antes de atribuir o valor ao hiddenField hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Você colocou a tag `<script>` no head da página?

Pois se colocou e está tentando atribuir um valor não vai dar certo mesmo, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Pois como não carregou a página por completo você não vai conseguir atribuir valor a nenhum elemento.

Pra resolver isso você pode por o `<script>` no final da `<body>`, exemplo:

**Página.aspx**:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID.ToString() %>").value = 'Token';
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(HiddenField1.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um dos motivos pelo qual ele pode estar perdendo o valor quando passado para o cs, é por causa do runat="server" com esta tag ele perde o valor mesmo a cada post. Tente retirar o runat e buscar o valor por FindControl

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Tive um problema parecido e resolvi colocando o HiddenField dentro de um UpdatePanel que estava usando anteriormente.